# Django cannot get the current user using rest-auth/user/

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am using Django with React and I am able to login the user with http://127.0.0.1:8000/rest-auth/login/' and register user with http://127.0.0.1:8000/rest-auth/registration/

I am trying to get the current user:

```
axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/rest-auth/user/')
    .then(res => {
        console.log(res)
    })
```

But I am getting the following error:

```
GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/rest-auth/user/ 403 (Forbidden)
```

I also tried it on postman and I get the following:

```
{
    "detail": "Authentication credentials were not provided."
}
```

Can someone show me the correct way to do it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you inspect the request and see if the session cookie is being sent with the request?

Answer (score 1):

This is because your route needs `Authorization token`.

```
axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/rest-auth/user/, {
       headers: {'Authorization': "Bearer " + token}
    })
    .then(res => {
        console.log(res)
    })
```

Comment: could you explain what does "Bearer" mean here?

Comment: To know about Bearer, follow [this link](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/120244)